# keras ограничить значения выходного слоя вектором значений

Tags: keras, tensorflow

у меня есть `x` входные данные

```
[[12,13,14],
..........
[32,15,19],
[23,16,17]
]
```

`y` = выходные данные

```
[[5]
..........
[7],
[9]
]
```

я точно уверен что `y` во всех случаях принимает значения `5,7,9`

подскажите какую модель мне лучше всего использовать.
на данный момент у меня

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(len(sequence)*10, input_shape=(len(sequence),), activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

после `fit`

```
yhat1 = md1.predict(xCheck)
```

я могу получить

```
3, 5, 11
```

что меня не устраивает

Answer (score 0):

> я точно уверен что `y` во всех случаях принимает значения `5,7,9`

Поскольку речь идёт явно о задаче **классификации** (целевые значения ограничены фиксированным списком), то видимо вам нужно использовать соответственные параметры при описании модели:

```
activation='sigmoid'
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
```

Использованные же вами параметры подходят для задачи **регрессии** (непрерывный спектр вещественных значений), что и видно по результатам работы модели.

Comment: activation='sigmoid'   === выдаст (-1,1) судя по описанию а мне нужно 5,7,9

Comment: @VitSaha Там нужно one hot encoding ещё делать для классификации, я потом код допишу, сейчас некогда

Comment: на данном етапе -- выдача -- полный бред. спасибо что откликнулись телега @ddnitecry